# Find the ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_{12})$ and find their orders.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

So I have shown in an earlier problem that the ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ are precisely the diagonal matrices. It seems to me that for the same reasons that those ideals needed to be diagonal, matrices with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ will need to be diagonal. Furthermore, there must be additional conditions on which elements will work to generate the ideals, and my intuition is telling me that a matrix with diagonal coefficients of $d$ will be an ideal iff $gcd(d,n)=1$  or $gcd(d,n)\neq1$, but i'm having trouble making headway either way. Can somebody give me some advice? Thanks yall!

Comment: It is a theorem that for any commutative ring $R$, left ideals of $M_n(R)$ are unions of columns with elements from some ideal $I \lhd R$, right ideals of $M_n(R)$ are unions of rows with elements from some ideal $I \lhd R$, and two-sided ideals are matrices with entries from some ideal $I \lhd R$.

Comment: Also, diagonal matrices do not form an ideal of $M_2(\mathbb R)$, since any ideal containing the identity matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ must coincide with the whole ring.

Comment: @lisyarus can you link me to this result plz? i can't find it

Comment: I think if you use that the matrix ring of a product is the product of the matrices ring it will be much easier. What I mean is that $M_{n}(A \times B) \simeq M_{n}(A) \times M_{n}(B)$

Comment: @LeoLerena so you mean to make $$M_n(\mathbb{Z_{12})=M_n(\mathbb{Z_{2})\timesM_n(\mathbb{Z_{2})\timesM_n(\mathbb{Z_{3})$$?

Comment: Actually in this case it's $M_{n}(\mathbb Z_4) \times M_{n}(\mathbb Z_3)$. I'm just saying that you can use this but what @lisyarus said is much evident to prove. Either way, it's interesting to look at the many ways of thinking about this.